# How would you get a document field?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore db

```
users
  vaffle
    alias: "Vaffle"
    gemcount: 10
```

How can I access a document field? 
What I've tried:

```
let ref = db.collection("users").doc("vaffle")
this.alias = ref.data().alias
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have right now is a reference, which doesn't contain any data.  It's just a pointer to a document.  You have to query the reference to get the data in the document it refers to:

```
let ref = db.collection("users").doc("vaffle")
ref.get().then(snapshot => {
    let alias = snapshot.data().alias
})
```

See the documentation on [reading data in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).